# Does FindFit use symbolic differentiation?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting, implementation-details

Does FindFit use symbolic differentiation when optimizing by least squares a non-linear function?

Answer (score 4):

`FindFit` does perform symbolic differentiation by default. It has the option to use finite differences instead via the option `Gradient -> "FiniteDifference"`.

There is worked example in the documentation [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFit.html#90513975).

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does. You can see this by using a function that prints the argument passed to the function evaluated in the `FindFit` procedure.
For example you could use this little setup:

```
data = Table[{x, 2.5*Exp[x]}, {x, 0, 1, 0.1}];
f[a_, x_] := Block[{}, Print[x]; a*Exp[x]]
FindFit[data, f[a, x], {a}, x]
```

What you will notice, when you execute the code, is that in addition to the correct result `a = 2.5` the `Print` routine yields the output `x`. This means that the function `f` has been evaluated symbolically by Mathematica, otherwise you would have gotten a list of numerical values, which would correspond to points where  `f` would have been evaluated numerically.

Comment: Since `FindFit` is not `HoldAll`, before `FindFit` is executed, `f[a, x]` is evaluated and the result is passed to `FindFit`.  I'm afraid this example does not show what `FindFit` does with the expression it gets.  -- BTW, I think you're probably right about `FindFit` differentiating, but I don't know how to prove it as yet.

Comment: Ok, I did not realise that. Thanks for the info. I will leave this answer up for now, because I think your comment is interesting, but I am glad to remove it. Sorry for the misinformation.

Comment: I'm not sure if derivatives are used, but you get slight differences using a symbolic function and a numeric black box.  For example, `f[a_, x_] := a*Exp[x]; g[a_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] := a*Exp[x];` yield values of `a` that differ by `10^15`.  The symbolic one is about ten times faster on your example.  It suggests derivatives, imo, but perhaps it's not conclusive.

Comment: Ok, now this example convinces me that Mathematica does not use symbolic differentiation: `data = Table[{x, Pi*x}, {x, 0, 1, 1}]; FindFit[data, a*x, {a}, x]` yields `{a -> 3.14159}` and not `{a -> Pi}`, which should be the case if Mathematica would differentiate symbolically.

Comment: `Pi == a /. FindFit[data, a*x, {a}, x]` evaluates to `True`, though, and working precision is `MachinePrecision`.  `FindFit` cannot (or will not) return exact, infinite precision answers.  The result is the same as `Pi` to 150 digits if I use `WorkingPrecision -> 150`.